# Passing a list to a nested vector function

Tags: equation-solving, function-construction

In order to apply a newton-rhapson algorithm to solve a set of nonlinear vector equations such as these,

```
f[x_, y_] = {x^2 - 3*y + 6, (y + 1)^2 - x - 33}
```

I need to nest the update function to run a few times:

```
newtit[x_, y_] =  {x, y} - Inverse[D[f[x, y], {{x, y}}]].f[x, y]
```

However, when using `Nest[]` I cannot seem to pass a list of arguments (`{2,2}`) to this function.

```
Nest[newtit, {2, 2}, 2]
```

To be clear why I don't just use `Solve[]`, I want to use this algorithm to solve a larger and more complicated set of vector equations. I am quite new to mathematica, but the syntax I use for passing lists to functions would be (`f@@{2,2}`), I can't use this form in `Nest[]`. What should I use in this case?

Comment: Thanks, those are insightful, but both entries seem to only handle a single input argument to the function `f`, or am I not looking into the arguments well enough?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Nest[newtit @@ # &, {2, 2}, 2]
```

> {477912/142961, 2239654/428883}

Comment: Thanks! What does the syntax here mean exactly?

Comment: @FlorisvanElteren, thanks for the accept. `f@@expr` replaces the head of `expr` by `f`; i.e., the head of `{2,2}` (i.e. `List`) is replaced by `newtit` giving `newtit[2,2]`.  (see [Apply (@@)](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Apply.html) )

Comment: Alternatively, `f` should have been directly defined for vector input: `f[{x_, y_}] := {x^2 - 3*y + 6, (y + 1)^2 - x - 33}; newtit[{x_, y_}] = {x, y} - Inverse[D[f[{x, y}], {{x, y}}]].f[{x, y}]`. Then `Nest[newtit, {2, 2}, 2]` just works.